# Second MySQL Query not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have a webpage which sends a query to my MySQL database to retrieve information about my company's suppliers and echos the results (all fine so far). It then makes a second query to check if there are any known contacts associated with that supplier:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $contact = $row["contact"];
    echo $row["name"] . "<br>" . $row["category"] . "<br>" . "Telephone: " .
        $row["telephone"] . "<br>" . "Fax: " . $row["fax"] . "<br>" .
        $row["email"] . "<br>" . $row["address"] . "<br>" .
        $row["postcode"] . "<br><br>" . "Contact: " .
        $contact . "<br>";
    $resultContact = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE name =
        '$contact'");
    while($rowContact = mysqli_fetch_array($resultContact)) {
        echo $rowContact["telephone"] . "<br>" . $rowContact["email"];
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

(`$row` is from the first query and works.) However, `echo $rowContact["telephone"] . "<br>" . $rowContact["email"];` just prints whitespace.

Thanks

**EDIT:** if I use a string literal in the Where clause, it works as it should. However, I used variables in exactly the same way as I am now in the first query and that works! I am confused :(

**EDIT 2:** the first query: `$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM suppliers WHERE LOWER(name) = LOWER('$searchText')");`

**EDIT 3:** the result of doing `var_dump($resultContact);`: `object(mysqli_result)#3 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(4) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) }` I'm guessing this means that the query is coming back with the table ok, but the Where clause isn't comparing the contact name as I want it to...

Comment: Should `WHERE name = '$contact'` be `WHERE name = '$row["name"]'`

Comment: do a var_dump $resultContact

Comment: Why are you doing two queries instead of querying both tables at once with a JOIN?

Comment: What does `var_dump($rowContact)` show?

Comment: Sean WM - No, because in the table "contacts", name gives the name of the contact, whereas in the table "suppliers", name gives the name of the company. I want to compare the name of the contact in the "suppliers" table ($contact) with the name of the contact in the "contacts" table (name).

Answer (score 0):

Your query must be mysql_query, not mysqli_query.
This is the correct code:

```
//Your db connection
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('database');

//queries and data
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM suppliers WHERE LOWER(name) = LOWER('$searchText')");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $contact = $row["contact"];
    echo $row["name"] . "<br>" . $row["category"] . "<br>" . "Telephone: " .
        $row["telephone"] . "<br>" . "Fax: " . $row["fax"] . "<br>" .
        $row["email"] . "<br>" . $row["address"] . "<br>" .
        $row["postcode"] . "<br><br>" . "Contact: " .
        $contact . "<br>";
    $resultContact = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE name =
        '$contact'");
    while($rowContact = mysql_fetch_array($resultContact)) {
        echo $rowContact["telephone"] . "<br>" . $rowContact["email"];
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: This throws "Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given" on the line of the while

Comment: Can you give the first sql query

Comment: Also, why can't I use mysqli_query?

Comment: You can use.. but mysql_query is very easy to use: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php, http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: Checkout your connection and the first query. Try adding print_r($row); if the data shows as an array the first query is working. Next you can add print_r($rowContact); to try the second query. Thats all

Comment: Hi, as I explained before, I already know that the first query is working and I have already tried printing $rowContact (I did attempt to solve this myself rather than immediately asking for help)

Comment: @SureshMichael what are you talking about, that it is easier to use mysql than mysqli, it's pretty much the same, though mysqli have some extra and better features!